# How to simulate from bivariate time series using VAR in R?

Tags: time-series, r, simulation

### Background

I've run into a problem while trying to simulate from an existing time series using a VAR. My aim is to simulate future "trajectories" which I'd like to integrate in an existing MCS, so my question is about simulating, not forecasting.

My time series looks like this - sorry for the mess, I was not able to recreate my problem with simulated data:

```
dat <- structure(list(A = c(59.388, 63.85725, 63.09975, 62.34225, 62.721, 
                 63.40275, 64.9935, 67.4175, 68.85675, 73.25025, 77.568, 62.19075, 
                 82.719, 80.67375, 81.12825, 86.8095, 88.173, 89.76375, 92.8695, 
                 100.1415, 97.49025, 95.82375, 88.0215, 81.43125, 69.69, 69.31125, 
                 74.9925, 81.0525, 87.4155, 76.12875, 71.28075, 76.659, 72.49275, 
                 72.8715, 72.64425, 75.75, 75.52275, 76.2045, 78.55275, 78.477, 
                 77.03775), 
           B = c(81.09619, 86.08957, 77.85974, 73.88353, 74.53082, 
                 58.44104, 59.08833, 59.411975, 61.21514, 71.987895, 76.981275, 
                 45.49524, 57.562575, 49.28651, 61.353845, 65.6537, 57.51634, 
                 64.91394, 70.64708, 72.542715, 58.44104, 58.394805, 59.689385, 
                 58.99586, 54.511065, 57.23893, 62.833365, 69.07509, 70.18473, 
                 67.41063, 76.28775, 90.281543330251, 92.439176669749, 92.50082330251, 
                 96.38456330251, 92.47, 88.185556669749, 89.449313330251, 86.521096669749, 
                 69.784026669749, 58.410216669749)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                         -41L))
```

### Current Approach

My current approach is as follows: I fit a VAR using the `tsDyn`'s `lineVar`-function, and then I simulate a "trajectory" using `VAR.sim` from the same package. However, when I plot the original time series, extended by my simulation, the results look suspicious:

```
library(tsDyn)
library(tidyverse)

# Fit the VAR:
fit <-
  tsDyn::lineVar(data = dat,
                 lag = 1,
                 model = "VAR")

# Extract coefficients:
coefs <- fit$coefficients

# Simulate from VAR:
set.seed(1)

sim <-
  as.data.frame(
    tsDyn::VAR.sim(B = coefs,
                   n = 100,
                   starting = tail(dat, 1))) %>% 
  rename(A = "V1",
         B = "V2") 

# Plot the original time series and the simulated trajectory:
ggplot(dat %>% 
         add_case(.,
                  sim) %>% 
         mutate(time = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
         pivot_longer(cols = A:B)) +
  geom_path(aes(y = value,
                x = time,
                color = name)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 41, 
             linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_classic()
```

### Problem

[image: The original time series (left of dashed line), extended by the simulated trajectory]

It is easy to see that the simulated trajectory has far less variance than the original time series, both variables are oscillating around the last known data points.
I'm aware that a VAR has assumptions about stationarity etc. that may not be met by the original time series, but even in case those assumtions are not fullfilled: Shouldn't the variation of the original time series be carried over to the simulation? I'm confused whether this outcome is a result of my model choice not being adequate, or of some mistake in my code.

### Questions

1. What is the reason for the low variance in the simulations?
2. How to simulate plausible trajectories instead?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.